# Web specifications and standards

Tags: html, css, web

can anyone give me few examples of web specifications standards as i don't understand what are they.

I have looked at https://www.w3.org/ , but i still don't pick anything that would make sense to me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have *specific* questions about something you don't understand in the technology and standards, we can help with that.

Comment: This question is equally broad as it is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web Spécification & standard is guide-lines and roules that should be respected as [w3.org](http://www.w3.org) note that for example every html document should start with `<html> </html>` starting tag and closing tag another  way of saying this your web pages need to be validated using [w3.org validator](https://validator.w3.org)